# Need to pull out XML node as its own data subset instead of added columns using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, ssis

I am working on parsing data out of a SSIS package .dtsx file.  I have most things working.  One added data bit I want to get is information about parameter bindings on execute SQL script sections.
Here is what the XML looks like:

```
<SQLTask:SqlTaskData xmlns:SQLTask="www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask" 
SQLTask:Connection="{37575B9B-BC41-4E1A-98FC-1C1B276F8394}" 
SQLTask:SqlStatementSource="INSERT INTO tblRunLog (&#xA;      StartedTimestamp, &#xA;      UserID, &#xA;      MachineID, &#xA;      ApplicationID, &#xA;      SystemID,&#xA;      ProgramID,&#xA;      RunDate,&#xA;      Client &#xA; ) &#xA;VALUES ( &#xA;      ?,&#xA;      REPLACE (?, 'ad-ent\', ''),&#xA;      ?,&#xA;      ?,&#xA;      ?,&#xA;      ?,&#xA;      CONVERT( VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 120 ),&#xA;      'ALL'&#xA;)&#xA;SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT) AS RunLogId&#xA;" 
SQLTask:ResultType="ResultSetType_SingleRow">
<SQLTask:ResultBinding 
SQLTask:ResultName="RunLogId" 
SQLTask:DtsVariableName="User::RunLogId" />
<SQLTask:ParameterBinding SQLTask:ParameterName="0" SQLTask:DtsVariableName="System::StartTime" SQLTask:ParameterDirection="Input" SQLTask:DataType="7" SQLTask:ParameterSize="-1" />
<SQLTask:ParameterBinding SQLTask:ParameterName="1" SQLTask:DtsVariableName="System::UserName" SQLTask:ParameterDirection="Input" SQLTask:c="129" SQLTask:ParameterSize="-1" />
<SQLTask:ParameterBinding SQLTask:ParameterName="2" SQLTask:DtsVariableName="System::MachineName" SQLTask:ParameterDirection="Input" SQLTask:DataType="129" SQLTask:ParameterSize="-1" />
<SQLTask:ParameterBinding SQLTask:ParameterName="3" SQLTask:DtsVariableName="System::PackageName" SQLTask:ParameterDirection="Input" SQLTask:DataType="129" SQLTask:ParameterSize="-1" />
<SQLTask:ParameterBinding SQLTask:ParameterName="4" SQLTask:DtsVariableName="User::SystemId" SQLTask:ParameterDirection="Input" SQLTask:DataType="3" SQLTask:ParameterSize="-1" />
<SQLTask:ParameterBinding SQLTask:ParameterName="5" SQLTask:DtsVariableName="User::DTSX_Path" SQLTask:ParameterDirection="Input" SQLTask:DataType="129" SQLTask:ParameterSize="-1" />
</SQLTask:SqlTaskData>
```

Here is the SQL code I have so far

```
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
     'www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS DTS
,'www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask' AS SQLTask
   )

select 
     A.ProjectItem.value('(./@SQLTask:Connection)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS ConnectionID
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./@SQLTask:SqlStatementSource)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') AS SQLStatement
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./@SQLTask:ResultType)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS ResultType
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ResultBinding/@SQLTask:ResultName)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as ResultName
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ResultBinding/@SQLTask:DtsVariableName)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as ResultDtsVariableName
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:ParameterName)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as p1name
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:DtsVariableName)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as p1var
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:ParameterDirection)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as p1dir
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:DataType)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as p1type
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:ParameterSize)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as p1size
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:ParameterSize)[1]','nvarchar(max)') as p2
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:ParameterName)[2]','nvarchar(max)') as p3
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:ParameterName)[3]','nvarchar(max)') as p4
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:ParameterName)[4]','nvarchar(max)') as p5
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:ParameterName)[5]','nvarchar(max)') as p6
    ,A.ProjectItem.value('(./SQLTask:ParameterBinding/@SQLTask:ParameterName)[6]','nvarchar(max)') as p7


    FROM ##tmp_SSISpkgControlFlow cf
        CROSS APPLY Cf.SqlTaskQry.nodes('./*') AS A(ProjectItem)
        where cf.tasktype like '%ExecuteSQLTask%'
```

I can get to the data I want, but I want to actaully pull it as a subset and then just have a reference to the original data set with dynamic rows as needed rather than static pulls that are null when data is not there.
I tinkered around with it some and cannot get what I want to work.  Combinations I could get to run using /* never came up with the XML data.

Example of one of my tries at it that just returns empty strings:

```
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
     'www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS DTS
,'www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask' AS SQLTask
   )
select 

    A.ProjectItem.query('.').query('./SQLTask:SqlTaskData[@SQLTask:ParameterBinding]/*') ExecPkgTaskQry
    FROM ##tmp_SSISpkgControlFlow cf
        CROSS APPLY Cf.SqlTaskQry.nodes('./*') AS A(ProjectItem)
        where cf.tasktype like '%ExecuteSQLTask%'
```

Any help you SQL+XML guys can give would be awesome.

Update, for others looking for answers.  Here is what my prototype code looks like after fixing my bug:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (
     'www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts' AS DTS
,'www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dts/tasks/sqltask' AS SQLTask
   )
select *
from (
    select 
        data.*
        ,Pnodes.x.value('(@SQLTask:ParameterName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS ParameterName
        ,Pnodes.x.value('(@SQLTask:DtsVariableName)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS DtsVariableName
        ,Pnodes.x.value('(@SQLTask:ParameterDirection)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS ParameterDirection
        ,Pnodes.x.value('(@SQLTask:DataType)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS DataType
        ,Pnodes.x.value('(@SQLTask:ParameterSize)[1]', 'VARCHAR(250)') AS ParameterSize
    from (
        select 
            cf.TaskName, cf.RowID,
            A.ProjectItem.query('.').query('./SQLTask:SqlTaskData[SQLTask:ParameterBinding]/*') ParameterData
        FROM ##tmp_SSISpkgControlFlow cf
            CROSS APPLY Cf.SqlTaskQry.nodes('.') AS A(ProjectItem)
        where cf.tasktype like '%ExecuteSQLTask%'
    ) as data
        CROSS APPLY data.ParameterData.nodes('./*') AS Pnodes(x)    
    where len(cast(data.ParameterData as varchar(max))) > 0
) as datatwo
where datatwo.ParameterName is not null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't clear to me what you're trying to achieve actually, but a simple mistake that make your 2nd query returns no result is in this part :

```
./SQLTask:SqlTaskData[@SQLTask:ParameterBinding]/*
```

`SqlTaskData` element in the XML you posted doesn't have attribute `SQLTask:ParameterBinding`. It supposed to be child element instead of attribute :

```
./SQLTask:SqlTaskData[SQLTask:ParameterBinding]/*
```

Comment: Thanks.  I am creating a standardized documentation set for SSIS packages by parsing out the XML.